# Node.js req vs req.stream.session when accessing alpnProtocol property

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

The use of `allowHTTP1` is illustrated in the [Node.js v14.0.0 docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/http2.html#http2_alpn_negotiation):

> ```
> const server = http2.createSecureServer(
>     { cert, key, allowHTTP1: true },
>     onRequest
> ).listen(4443);
>
> function onRequest(req, res) {
>     // Detects if it is a HTTPS request or HTTP/2
>     const { socket: { alpnProtocol } } = (req.httpVersion === '2.0')? req.stream.session : req;
>     res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'application/json' });
>     res.end(JSON.stringify({
>         alpnProtocol,
>         httpVersion: req.httpVersion
>     }));
> }
> ```

As shown in the example, the following line is used to decide whether the user is using HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2, so that it can get the `alpnProtocol` value:

```
const { socket: { alpnProtocol } } = (req.httpVersion === '2.0')? req.stream.session : req;
```

This allows it to use `req.stream.session` or just `req` depending on the HTTP version. However, replacing the line with the following still works despite the HTTP version:

```
const { socket: { alpnProtocol } } = req;
```

**What is the reason for using a ternary statement to choose between `req` and `req.stream.session` when using just `req` works?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a HTTP request, `req` and `res` will be instances of `IncomingMessage` and `ServerResponse` respectively. In a HTTP2 request, `req` and `res` will instead be instances of `Http2ServerRequest` and `Http2ServerResponse`. `IncomingMessage` does not have `stream` because HTTP does not support bi-directional `Duplex` streams; HTTP2 made it a feature. `alpnProtocol` identifies the protocol in use by its ALPN identifier, which is one of: `h3`, `h2`, `h2c`, or `http/1.1`.

**Edit:**

`alpnProtocol` from either are almost identical, only difference is its `h2c` if unencrypted, and a related property `encrypted`. See how [it is defined in the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/http2/core.js#L956-L965).